# jquery slider... how to auto height?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

http://jsfiddle.net/VDz4J/5/

I have a content slider... check the fiddle for the test case..

what I'd like to achive is that when I slide to a (whatever) .page_content the webpage would need to adjust the height to the **current column** (panel or whatever)....now, obviously it adjusts to the highest panel...

and please assume, that the content is loaded dynamically, so I do the slide first, then load the content inside... (not vice-versa... for status indication purposes)....so I don't know the panel heights in advance like in this test case...

I don't want to delete content from already loaded (but hidden) panels just to get the proper height!

any ideas? can it be done just in CSS, do I need to change my markup? Please, I am desperate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not great (or even good) at javascript and animations but here's a solution.

Just animate the container div's height to equal the height of the content div that's being displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/VDz4J/15/

Comment: Yeah, I did it too... almost the same way

http://jsfiddle.net/VDz4J/16/

The only problem is, I need to add the animation to after the content is fully loaded...:S

Thanks for the help1

Comment: I have updated it further Using the .css() so you dont see the background resize http://jsfiddle.net/VDz4J/17/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out :
For `.page_content` set `height:auto;` (and remove the fixed height for the columns).

Then when you click on a menu link adjust the height    :

> ```
> $("#webpage").css("height",$(".pg_"+$pg).height());
> ```

here are the changes :
http://jsfiddle.net/VDz4J/14/

Also supposing you would use a function such as load (To load the content dynamically), you could take benefit of it's callback :

```
$('.pg_'+$pg).load('content_url.php', function() {
   $("#webpage").css("height",$(this).height());
});
```